# Magento 1 Automatic Product Imagem Slider Module

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm searching for a Magento 1.9 module that provides automatic replacement of images in the product's page, but cant find one.

Does anybody knows one?

Thank you,

Comment: what do you mean by automatic replacement of images ?

Comment: For instance, if a product has 3 images, i want those images to transition (just like in a slider) automatically. 

Ty for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension for change product image.
https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/product-images-slider.html

Comment: Thank you Rakesh, thats what i'm looking for. But is there a free module with the same functionality?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any link of free extension.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand you, *automatic replacement of images* is something that's called banner slider?

So this seems to have quite good reviews

https://marketplace.magento.com/magestore-magestore-bannerslider.html